# BASH script to add username, password and multiple groups

Tags: bash, multiple-users

**ASSUMPTIONS:**

I have a file called **users.txt**

```
username:password:groups
user1:password:group1,group2,group3
user2:password:group3
user3:password:group1,group3
user4:password:group2,group3
```

**CODE**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME="users.txt"

while IFS=':' read USERNAME PASSWORD GROUPS
do

    echo "USERNAME" $USERNAME "PASSWORD" $PASSWORD "GROUPS" $GROUPS

done < "$FILENAME"
```

I want to be able to add a bunch of users to be able to do a samba share.  I have a full list of users to input.  I am having difficulty mostly with the groups.

Two biggest questions are, how to I get the groups as one string and how do I encrypt the password.

I have been through all tutorials on this site and none of them are working.

Simple to understand code would really help.  Thanks.

**UPDATED FINISHED WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
#!/bin/bash
# set filename
FILENAME="users.txt"

# loop through file 
while IFS=':' read USERNAME PASSWORD GROUPNAMES
do

    # add user and assign groups
    echo " "
    echo "ADDING USER: " $USERNAME
    useradd $USERNAME -G $GROUPNAMES

    # add password
    echo -e "$PASSWORD\n$PASSWORD\n" | passwd $USERNAME

    # add user to samba
    echo -e "$PASSWORD\n$PASSWORD\n" | smbpasswd -a $USERNAME

done < "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: Avoid using all uppercase variable, you might end up conflicting with built-in variables.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, but I'll know that for future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use GROUPS as a variable name : it's a read-only variable already used by the system. Just change the name of this variable.

Comment: Good point and a useful piece of advice but it's not an answer.

Comment: @Tom Fenech Could you explain me more please? I tested it, it makes the script working. Is it about the encryption question?

Comment: OH MY GOSH!  I am so frustrated that it was that easy!  This was the number one problem I had and couldn't get past it.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Yeah, I still have to figure out the encryption part, but the rest of my code will be easy to figure out.  I was mostly stuck on why GROUPS wouldn't work.

Comment: My apologies, I misinterpreted the question. It wasn't clear to me that the `while read` wasn't setting the variables correctly, I thought that they were asking how to use them. +1 from me.

Comment: @user2470057 : I'm not a SO master to give advices, but as a new user, you should take care of asking only one question at a time on this site; so the encryption question could be another new question

Comment: @yolenoyer It was a combined issue, I couldn't figure out anything at all, so out of desperation, I shortened my script to the most basic part so that I could figure out what the problem was.  There are enough encryption questions on this site that will allow me to complete my code, if not, I will ask that specific question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the password encryption part but I can give a suggestion about the groups. Inside of your loop, you could do this:

```
read -ra groups_array -d, <<<"$groups"
```

Now you have an array containing each group as an element. You can pass them as separate arguments to a command using the expansion `"${groups_array[@]}"` or access them individually using `"${groups_array[0]}"`, `"${groups_array[1]}"`, etc.

Note that I am using lowercase variable names - this is intentional. Uppercase names should be reserved for use by the shell, as otherwise you run the risk of overwriting important ones.

Answer (score -1):

Excellent script above: I used the code co create this working version.

#!/bin/bash

## This method includes the bash code and data in just one file

## Install this file, run it and remove it immediately for future use with a new server etc.

function setupUser()
{

## first, remove old instance of user in both linux and samba

echo "remove user: " $1
smbpasswd -d         $1
userdel              $1

## Now add new user in both linux and samba

echo "adding user: "$1
useradd $1  -G nogroup
echo -e "$2\n$2\n" | passwd $1
echo -e "$2\n$2\n" | smbpasswd -a $1
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

setupUser  tom         secret
setupUser  dick        secret
setupUser  harry       secret

Comment: please respect the SO style guide and change your formatting accordingly, thanks